# How to test uniqueness in a Model.clean() function?

Tags: python, django, django-models, constraints

I have a model with a `UniqueConstraint`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    title = models.CharField()
  
    class Meta:
        constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(
                          fields=['name', 'title'],
                          name="unique_name_and_title") ]
```

This works fine and raises an `IntegrityError` when 2 objects with the same values are created.

The problem is `UniqueConstraint` doesn't present a pretty `ValidationError` to the user. Usually, I would add these in the `Model.clean()` class, but if I do this then it will fail on an `Update` because the instance being updated will already be present:

```
def clean(self):
    if MyModel.objects.filter(title=self.title, name=self.name):
             raise ValidationError({'title':'An object with this name+title already exists'})
```

I How do I create a `ValidationError` that passes if it's an UPDATE not an INSERT?

I know I could do this on a `ModelForm` and use `self.instance` to check if the instance already exists, but I want to apply this to the Model class and not have to rely on a ModelForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the object from the queryset you check:

```
def clean(self):
    qs = MyModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(title=self.title, name=self.name)
    if qs.exists():
        raise ValidationError({'title':'An object with this name+title already exists'})
    return super().clean()
```

If the object is not yet saved, it will check for `.exclude(pk=None)`, but that will not exclude any objects, since the primary key is non-nullable.

It is more efficient to use [**`.exists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) here, since it limits the bandwidth from the database to the Django/Python layer.

Comment: Can you please explain why `return super().clean()` is required?

Comment: @Austin `super().clean()` ensures if you have inherited a class (which you have with `model.Models` in this case) that you allow it to continue other processes that may be defined.

Comment: @Austin: because the Django model can have other validations. For example in a abstract (base) model, or because of a `unique_together` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together), although this is outdated. Better to preserve base behavior as well.

Comment: Cool, got it. Thanks.